# Set height for border-left

Tags: html, css

**HTML code:**

```
<div class="program-contents">

   <div class="program-item"> ... </div>
   <div class="program-item"> ... </div>
   ...
   <div class="program-item"> ... </div>

</div>
```

**Styles for .program-contents:**

```
margin-left: 25px;
margin-top: -35px;
padding: 35px 25px 0 25px;
border-left: 2px solid #e2e0e0;
```

How can I **set height** for **border-left** of ***.program-contents*** as **90%**? I'm trying **not displays bottom part of border-left** for .program-contents. I need 90% of height of "border-left" for this block.

Comment: use `calc()` to achieve what you are looking for.

Comment: beware that `calc()` is [not at](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc) the "almost 100%" implementation stage yet.

Comment: Isn't `height of .program-contents - 10% of its height` = `90% of its height`?

Comment: "hrigth of .program-contents" - "10% of height of .program-contents"? - what is this?

Comment: How can I apply function calc() for "border-left"? We can't set height for "border-left"...

Comment: @JohnBupit Yes, I need 90% of height of "border-left" for this block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try using **pseudo-elements**. [Here's how](http://jsfiddle.net/47m9s/):

```
.program-contents {
    height: 300px;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: #EEE;

}

.program-contents::before {
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    content: ' ';
    border-left: 1px #AAA solid;
}
```

The [`:before`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#before-and-after) pseudo-element can be used to insert generated content before an element's content. I set its height to 90% of its parent (which is `.program-contents`), and then added a left border to it.

And if you need the border to be vertically centered, you can add `top: 5%`. Something [like this](http://jsfiddle.net/47m9s/1/):

```
.program-contents::before {    
    position: relative;
    top: 5%;
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    content: ' ';
    border-left: 1px #AAA solid;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use height & width for .program-contents.

This code does't work:

.program-listing .program-contents { display: none; margin-left: 25px; margin-top: -35px; padding: 35px 25px 0 25px; border-left: 2px solid #e2e0e0; }
.program-listing .program-contents::before {
    display: block;
    height: 90%;
    content: ' ';
    border-left: 1px #AAA solid;
}

Comment: If you can't set the height for `.program-contents`, try this: http://jsfiddle.net/47m9s/2/

Comment: John, thank you! Yes, it works. You helped me very much.